# Converting MSDN license to full, commercial license

Tags: licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I had to throw a machine together in a bit of a hurry- to replace a machine that suddenly failed (no one had bothered to keep a "warm" backup)
It has Windows Server 2008 and SQL 2008

The snag is, I installed them off our MSDN subscription media, due to me not having "licensed" software.
I need to put this machine into production.

We are in the process of buying the licenses from a MS reseller now.
Is there a way to "convert" the MSDN license to production on both Windows Server and SQL?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware No.

The license keys are hardcoded against the distribution medium. Therefore if you use a KMS key on an MSDN media for example it won't work, unless the license is issued by a KMS server. The same rule applies to Retail MSDN media.

Your easiest bet will be to do a re-install of the OS using the new keys. You shouldn't loose anything int he process. I recently did an in-place re-install of one of my 2008 R2 boxes and no issues.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, its a re-install, but no need for a clean install.

If you have SQL Server Developer edition installed, you can do an 'in-place' upgrade to 
enterprise/standard.

Answer (score 2):

***No need to reinstall.***

Atually no. Sorry, Licenses 2008 are hardcoded.... but not tied to the media. 2008 is 2008. All 2008 CD's (Windows) have KMS keys installed. Just replace your license key using the slmgr.vbs script. If you use a KMS, then it is a KMS activation anyway 
(because possibly your company has a KMS in the domain). If you used a MSDN key... replace it. Again, slmgr.vbs. Point. No way to find out the install was a MSDN originally.

SQL.... in place upgrade via command line.